# How to auto-sync all Telegram supergroup users to a channel?

Tags: telegram

Can I automatically add all users that join a supergroup into a channel?

Comment: I've added a pretty general answer, but if that does not satisfy, maybe you can elaborate more on the situation if you're welcoming other solutions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an existing way of doing that, but maybe it can be achieved via the API.

Note: I heard of people that added multiple users to channels and then got banned/restricted in some way or another. I don't know (and couldn't find out) what are the limitations before it would happen.

I think that the most probable way is to use the [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/api) to achieve that, maybe by creating a little script/app that will read the users from your group and add them to the channel.
Have a look at the [messages.addChatUser](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.addChatUser) method.

A question on StackOverflow that asks how to do it with a [bot](https://telegram.org/blog/bot-revolution):

- [Add user to channel automatically when user asks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448635/add-user-to-channel-automatically-when-user-asks)

If you don't want to risk anything (such as being restricted), I would go by engaging users to join by themselves:

- Create a nice post with an image an a button to the new related channel.
- Forward messages from the channel to the group.
- Pin an invitation message to the chat (assuming you're the admin).

Note that if you're not the admin, they will probably won't be happy with your advertising..